# Origin and Host headers for same domain requests

Tags: ajax, http, rest, http-headers, csrf

We have RESTful JSON endpoints serving AJAX requests, with the desire to support Cross Origin Resource Sharing.  We are locking things down to ensure that we don't have to worry about Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks.  Part of the approach we are using is to check for the presence of a Origin header and verify that it is included in a whitelist of approved Origins.  However, we have noticed that some browsers (Chrome and Safari among them) include the Origin header with AJAX POST requests, even when originating from the same domain (so not a CORS request).

Since we would prefer to not require our users to have to whitelist the same domain that the REST endpoints are being served from, we would like to determine automatically whether or not a given request is "Same Domain" or "Cross Origin".  To do this, right now our best attempt is to watch for the presence of an Origin header, and if it exists, compare it with the value of the Host header.  Our logic is that if the Origin matches the Host, then this request must be "Same Domain" and so we do not need to check for the Origin in the whitelist.

Here is a snippet of the server-side JS code we are thinking of using to accomplish this:

```
     if (typeof (headers["Origin"]) !== "undefined" &&
         headers["Origin"].replace(new RegExp("^.*?//"), "") !== headers["Host"] &&
         !contains(allowedOrigins, headers.Origin) ) {
         return false;
     } else {
         return true;
     }
```

The regexp comparison is needed because Origin header will come in looking like this:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

Whereas the Host header will come in looking like this:

```
localhost:8080
```

So I use that regexp to strip off the leading http://.

The problem is that we haven't seen any other implementations using or discussing this approach.  This concerns us that maybe this isn't an appropriate method, for some reason.  So, the question is - **is comparing the Host header with the Origin header a safe way to determine if a request originates from the same domain**?

Also, is removing the leading protocol:// from the Origin as I've shown going to always yield the proper value in relation to Host?

Comment: Do you consider a threat that the Origin header can be fake? Shouldn't it be more preferrable to whitelist ip-addresses and check remote ip address of a request instead of http headers?

Comment: We are more concerned with innocent users having their session abused with CSRF attacks then with malicious users spoofing headers.  In that scenario, an Origin header cannot be faked.  So that isn't a concern.

Comment: I came to the same question that you (see linked posts). In my opinion this approach is more clean than the white list when avoiding CSRF. Notice also that this question has a broader scope than AJAX, like Websockets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advice you to instead check for the Ajax header:
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

Same-origin Ajax can add custom headers and almost all popular frameworks such as jQuery adds X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest.

For CORS however, custom headers provoke a pre-flight HTTP OPTIONS request.

Thus, if you see X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest (or any other custom header) without a pre-flight you know it's a same-origin Ajax call.

Comment: John your suggestion is pretty much exactly the route we decided to take on our own.  It's funny how spot on it is.  Great minds and all of that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach of comparing the Host header with the Origin header for determining same origin will fail if **you want to switch to HTTPS down the line** or we can say in case of **cross protocol request**.

Like your code will treat these two origins same.

`Origin : http://www.example.com
Origin : https://example.com`

Other approach will be using **[HTTP Referer](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Checking_Referer_Header) header**. But i will not prefer using it because spoofing it is not an impossible task.

My suggestion would be better play safe than sorry. Adding an extra item in list of allowed origins is not gonna give you so much pain.