# Origin check in Java Websockets to prevent CSRF

Tags: java, cross-domain, csrf, java-websocket, tyrus

I am programatically deploying a Java Websocket endpoint (JSR356 3.1) and I want it to validate the `Origin` request header value in order to mitigate CSRF attacks, and only accept handshake requests whose `Host` and `Origin` header values match.

It seems to me that the way to go is overriding the method:

[`ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.checkOrigin(String originHeaderValue)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html#checkOrigin-java.lang.String-)

(the implementation provided by Tomcat 8 always returns `true`), but the problem I see is that this method only has a single parameter, and I miss the host header value to compare this value against.

Also this class do not offer any method returning this information, so I see this method as useless, unless you are comparing the origin header value against a previously known host value or set of values, but this doesn't have any sense too, since my application could be seen under different, changing host names or IPs.

I am considering performing this validation inside the implementation of `modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig sec, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response)` where I can read all header values, but I am pretty sure that I am misunderstanding something.

So my question is:

What is the proper way to perform this validation?

Thanks,
Nacho

Comment: yeah it does not seem right; the API should have provided the application an opportunity to reject or accept the handshake.

Comment: Thanks @bayou.io, i am afraid so. I just tagged the question with `tyrus`, hoping a JSR expert can read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a little more into the problem I have concluded that the Websocket API (JSR-356) is designed to perform an origin check against a "white list", a series of predefined allowed origins (as you can see in [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLPRG/websockets.htm#WLPRG865) from Weblogic):

```
 ...
 import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig;

 public class MyConfigurator extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {
 ...  
     private static final String ORIGIN = "http://www.example.com:7001";

     @Override
    public boolean checkOrigin(String originHeaderValue) {
        return ORIGIN.equals(originHeaderValue)   
    }
 }
 ...
```

but unfortunately, this API do not contemplates the possibility of implementing a `Host` vs `Origin` header validation.

As a workaround, for those service providers that place the websocket endpoint behind the servlet stack (like Tomcat, where the Websocket machinery is triggered by the servlet filter `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter`) you can create an outer filter that enables threadlocal access to the request, in order to use it in the `checkOrigin()` method to get the `Host` header value.

This makes me wonder why this type of checking is not preferred over the white list solution, and just found this interesting post: [Origin and Host headers for same domain requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444914/origin-and-host-headers-for-same-domain-requests)